Problems with Google apps script in add-on. Running script/add-on on laptop works, running same script on Gmailapp (mobile) throws error
I have a function (addEmailsOfStudentsToBCC(e)) which fetches e-mail adresses from a Google sheet pending on the choices of the user on a formInput (select). If gets the e-mailadress of each selected student, pushes in a array and in the end the array gets pushed to the BCC of a draft e-mail.
Everything works like a sharm on the Gmail app on my laptop. When opening the same add-on with the same function on my mobile device (in Gmail-app)... It throws an Type errror:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at addEmailsOfStudentsToBCC(Main:174:16)
Logs also show that e['formInputs']['studentPicker'] is null on the mobile device but it returns an array with the chosen selection on a laptop.
The crazy thing is i have another function where teacher can select classes which use a similar way of working (e['formInputs'['classPicker'])
and that one works on laptop and mobile.
function addEmailsOfStudentsToBCC(e) {
  let studentsToMail = e['formInputs']['studentPicker']
  let toRecipients = []



studentsToMail.forEach((e) => {
    var listOfEmails = getMaillistFromClass(e)
    toRecipients.push(listOfEmails)
  })

  


 var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder().setUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction
    (CardService.newUpdateDraftBccRecipientsAction()
      .addUpdateBccRecipients(toRecipients))
    .build();
  return response;

 

}

I tried to check the logs but i'm kind of hopeless at the moment

Google Add-ons Restrictions
Since it wasn't stated what type of add-on you're using, Google actually has two types of add-ons: Google Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons. This information is specified on Types of add-ons where it states that

There are two types of add-ons you can build: Google Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons. For more information about each, see Add-on types.

According to Google Workspace Add-ons Restrictions

For the time being, Google Workspace Add-ons function on desktop web clients. Contextual triggering (that is, Gmail message reading) is also supported from within the Gmail mobile app. Non-contextual homepages are not yet available from the Gmail, Calendar, or Drive mobile apps. Google Workspace Add-ons are not available from mobile web browsers.

While Editor Add-ons states that

Editor Add-ons only function in desktop clients, not Android or iOS.

I'm guessing that you're using a Google Workspace Add-on. The first statement explains why the studentPicker behaves differently on mobile compared to the classPicker. You mentioned, The crazy thing is I have another function where the teacher can select classes, which uses a similar approach (e['formInputs']['classPicker']), and that one works on laptop and mobile. This highlights that it may not work consistently due to the existing restrictions.
